# What's the best way to translate "de Hercule famam acceperat"?

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

I'm translating the text:

> Pluto, qui de Hercule famam acceperat, eum benigne excepit
>
> ([*Fabulae Faciles*, 53](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/ritchie.html))

I chose to translate it as "Pluto, who had heard stories about Hercules, received him kindly". But I realize this is a loose translation.

A more literal translation would be, "Pluto, who had heard of the reputation concerning Hercules, received him with kindness".

Since I assume that the phrase "famam acceperat" is repeated a lot in Latin literature, I'm curious, what are some popular ways of translating it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First I must object to this horrible story. My abduction to your overworld by Hercules was illegal, and I am still angry at Pluto for it!

That said, I think your translation "heard stories about" is fine, although "stories" sometimes suggests something a bit more exciting or adventurous than *fama* does: it may be an account of something or someone, a story, or someone's reputation. Depending on context, "stories" may fit. "Who had heard about Hercules's reputation" is also fine.

The expression is indeed used by classical authors:

> Vespasianus in Italiam resque urbis intentus **adversam de Domitiano famam accipit**, tamquam terminos aetatis et concessa filio egrederetur... (Tacitus, *Historiae* IV.51)

[Church & Brodribb (1873)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0079%3Abook%3D4%3Achapter%3D51) translate this as "heard an unfavourable account of Domitianus", which I think is a very good translation. In your case, "had heard of Hercules" is possible, although the context seems to suggest something a bit stronger and more favourable.

> nam Romae neuter animi habitus satis dici enarrarique potest, nec [habitus animi] quo incerta exspectatione euentus ciuitas fuerat nec [habitus animi] quo **uictoriae famam accepit**. (Livius, *Ab Urbe Condita* XXVII.50.3)

Roberts (1912) translates this as "the enthusiasm which the report of the victory aroused". Translated a bit more literally, it would be "the state of mind in which they received the report of the victory". This is a bit different from Tacitus and from your story, in which it is about merely hearing news: Livius is describing *accipere* as a kind of action, as listening to a message and reacting to it, together comprising *accepit*. "Hear a report" or "receive a report" are good basic translations in such a context.

Comment: Still, he did take you back - how is life in the Underworld? ;)

Comment: @TheHonRose: Fair enough! He probably missed me. Being back is a dark and infernal blessing!

Comment: @Cerberus I think you fully answered my question. Thanks for your helpful words and delightful humor.

Comment: @ktm5124: Welcome to the site!